# Is deinitialization considered "data race free"?

Tags: swift, concurrency, race-condition, memory-barriers, swift3

In Swift, members of classes and structs will be deinitialised (destroyed) by a compiler generated function.

An object will be destroyed automatically, when there's no strong reference anymore. On whatever thread this last strong reference ceases to exist, the object will be destroyed on this thread. This will destroy all its struct members, and possibly destroy its member objects, iff this is the last strong reference as well.

A value of type struct will be destroyed automatically after it's scope ceases to exits. That is, on whatever thread this happens, this thread executes the deinitialization of the struct value.

I'm wondering if this deinitialization has been protected against data races. My first guess is, that it is not. But when it is not, *how* would one insert proper synchronisation primitives when the deinitialization of these member variables is generated by the compiler *AND* when there are potential data races?

I'll illustrate this problem with an example:

```
public class Foo {
    private let _syncQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "sync-queue", attributes: .serial)

    private var _array: [String] = [] 

    init() {
    }

    deinit {
    }

    func add(_ s: String) {
        _syncQueue.async {
            self._array.append(s)
        }
    }

}
```

This is simply a class whose instances can be used from any thread, and where calling the `add(_:)` method is thread-safe. So, in any scenario, the use of an object of type `Foo` should be thread-safe. Is it actually?

Well, iff the deinitialization is not synchronised, then it is not!

The problem realises when there is a last strong reference living in a thread which is not the same thread where previous accesses have been made which use synchronisation primitives (e.g. dispatch lib) AND iff this thread *happens* to be not synchronised with this other thread through some other unrelated operation.

I was able to actually generate this data race, which then occurs in the `deinit` method of `Foo`. It was actually not that easy to find certain usage scenarios where this happens and even worse, they do not *always* happen in the same scenario (depends on the current threads spawned by GCD). But eventually it happened, and with the help of the new Thread Sanitizer in Xcode 8 beta, I actually detected these.

But I'm still wondering if this, in the current Swift language, is considered as "behaves as expected" or whether this is actually a bug.

The latter would be the case if Swift would use some global fence which synchronises with any thread and is used before the deinitialization of values, but for some bug and in certain scenarios it is accidentally not used.

Comment: Possibly of interest: [How does Apple's Objective-C runtime do multithreaded reference counting without degraded performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942226/how-does-apples-objective-c-runtime-do-multithreaded-reference-counting-without).

Comment: This is a fascinating question that I am aggressively investigating the answer for.