# What's the difference between atomic reference counting and automatic reference counting?

Tags: swift, rust, automatic-ref-counting

I see ARC as an acronym used every now and then, but for example in Rust it's "atomic reference counting", and in Swift or ObjC they call it "automatic reference counting". What exactly is the difference? As far as I know they seem to behave the same way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually... totally different.

- **atomic**: comes from [atomicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)), it describes an operation that is executed *in one step*, that is an external observer cannot see any intermediate step: they only see the state before or after.
- **automatic**: means [done or produced as if by a machine](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/automatic).

---

On the Rust side, we have `Arc` and `Rc` which are reference counting pointers:

- `Rc` is the bare-bone reference-counting pointer: cloning it just increments a counter, and when the last `Rc` pointing to a particular piece of data is dropped, the counter falls down to 0 and that piece of data is dropped too.
- `Arc` is the atomic version of it, which means it is thread-safe and can be shared across threads (unlike `Rc`).

---

On the Swift side, `ARC` refers to Automatic Reference Counting, Swift's Garbage Collection mechanism which as the name implies is automatic (and invisible in the code).

Comment: One question remains: is Swift's reference counting atomic? (I guess it has to be ... ?)

Comment: Given that they are totally different I'm glad I asked! Thank you :)

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: I hope so! But we'll need a Swift expert to answer this.

Comment: It is threadsafe, if that's the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942226